# listview displaying multiple string arrays on item click

Tags: android, listview

I have two activities, the first contains a listview with 30 items displaying nationalities, the second activities containing also a listview should display the name of players from that nationalities when its clicked in the first activity. how can I do that with only two activities?
ps: I'm only learning from youtube and stackoverflow for a year now.

Comment: hm,... I think you should re-evaluate the structure of your app. So you have Activity A and B (A of course being your main activity) and  you want clicking on a list view item in activity A to display Activity B (which is an entire listview?). Why not have one List View...Each player should be an object. Each player object should have a nationality attribute. Clicking on a specific player should pop up maybe an alert dialog containing the players nationality and any other attributes you want them to have, no?

Comment: You can use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments)

Comment: This project is only for learning purposes, that's why I don't pay attention to style and structure. I have tried your solution in different way, but I got the code is too large error because I have a lot of data

Comment: Mohamed Mohaideen AH can you explain more?

Comment: Ahh...The all too common "Code is too large error". lol ok. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm learning and I will not stop!

Answer (score 0):

From the adapter attached to Activity A ListView, set onClickListener on each position of the ListView to launch Activity B via intent with nationality passed as an extra; in Activity B: you will retrieve the intent extra which is the nationality, hence, a POJO which features nationality and Lists of names of players would have been made and stored into database ( preferably using ROOM): and finally, retrieve from the database all the names of players that are stored in the database with respect to the nationality that is retrieved from intent extra. Your database query will be to load all data ( names of players) where nationality is equal to the retrieved nationality.

Your POJO which is also your Entity class (if using ROOM) could look as below ;

```
@Entity(tableName = "Data")
public class DataObject {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private Nationality nationality;
    private ArrayList<PlayersName> playersName;

    @Ignore
    public DataObject() {

        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.playersName = playersName;
    }



    public DataObject( int id, Nationality nationality, ArrayList<PlayersName> playersName) {

        this.id = id;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.playersName = playersName;
    }


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Nationality getNationality() {
    return nationality;
}

public void setNationality(Nationality nationality) {
    this.nationality = nationality;
}

public ArrayList<PlayersName> getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(ArrayList<PlayersName> name) {
    this.name = name;
}




}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this looks like exactly what I need. I will try that. Thanks again